# Using an opaque pointer to a non struct type

Tags: c, typedef, encapsulation, opaque-pointers

In my C programming, I use opaque-pointers to struct as a way to enforce abstraction and encapsulation of my code, in that manner :

interface_header.h:

```
 typedef struct s_mytype t_mytype;
```

defs_header.h:

```
struct s_mytype
{
/* Actual definition of the struct */
};
```

My problem I want to use a simple type as `t_mytype` (`char` for example), but not inform the interface about that. I can't just use `typedef char t_mytype`, since that would expose the the internals of the type.
I could just use void pointers, but at the cost of type-checking, and I'd rather avoid that.

Doing two typedef wont work either, since that throw an `typedef redefinition with different types` from the compiler.

I am also considering doing a struct with only one member, which will be my simple type, but would that be an overkill ?

Thanks for your answers.

Comment: If you need an opaque type, structures are necessary. Decide whether opaqueness or simplicity is more important. Remember that you’ll be passing pointers around.

Comment: Use the single member. It's a bit of boilerplate in your *source*, but the compiled code should't be different.

Comment: Can you do something similar to how `sockaddr` and `sockaddr_in` are implemented?

Comment: @MFisherKDX Ewww! (and how does that solve the problem?)

Comment: @FelixPalmen -- expose `sockaddr` in your API and use `sockaddr_in` in your implementation ??.

Comment: @MFisherKDX Could you elaborate a bit more on that ?

Comment: I'm going to withdraw my suggestion.  I tried implementing `s_mytype` as a 0 sized structure and `s_mytype_in` as a struct with a first member of type `s_mytype` and a second member of type `char` and then realized this is worse than your and @FelixPalmen's proposed solutions to use a struct with 1 member.  And on top of that, I discovered C does not necessarily allow 0 sized structures, although some compilers do. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/755305/empty-structure-in-c

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have to make a decision. With code like this:

```
typedef char myHandle;

frobnicate(myHandle *obj);
```

you already document the **intent** that client code should only use pointers to `myHandle` and never assume anything about the underlying type, so you should be able to change the `typedef` later -- **unless** there's "sloppy" client code making assumptions it shouldn't.

---

If you want to completely hide what's behind `myHandle`, a `struct` is your only option in C:

```
typedef struct myHandle myHandle;

frobnicate(myHandle *obj);
```

and only in a private header or implementation file, you will put

```
struct myHandle
{
    char val;
};
```

---

The first option is simpler because inside the implementation of `frobnicate()`, you can access your value simply using `*obj` while the second option requires to write `obj->val`. What you gain with the second version is that you **force** client code to be written correctly.

In terms of the resulting executable, both versions are equivalent.

Comment: I'll opt for the second version. That will be more consistent with the rest of my code, and I always prefer to enforce my intent rather than just stating it. And anyway, adding the syntactic overhead of `obj->val` is not much, since there will be not much code there, expect for the dereferencing part. Thanks for that answer, that helped me to make up my mind !

Comment: @VannTen the dereference is always needed with opaque handles/pointers, and with `obj->val`, the compiler just finds an offset of `0` to be added to the pointer, which is of course eliminated, so you'll have no additional overhead in the binary. I personally prefer to force correct usage of my interfaces (as far as this is possible) as well, but it's a matter of taste ;) Good question btw, I ran into the same design decision earlier.