Why can't I declare an extern array of elements with an incomplete type in C?
I am in the process of refactoring a codebase that is written in C, but I'm using a C++ compiler and I want to use a C compiler.
One thing I stumbled upon is that C++ allows extern arrays of elements with an incomplete type, while C does not.
For example, the following C program doesn't compile:
extern struct Foo foos[];

struct Foo {};

int main() {

}

Godbolt demo
Why does C not allow this? C does allow extern variables with incomplete types. Why are arrays an exception?

C++ allows extern arrays to incomplete types -- This is fools gold, as if you tried to get sizeof(foo) in the C++ code, you get the error that the type is incomplete.  C++ code now shows an error.

How would you calculate the address for any element in the array if you do not know the size of each element?

extern does not allocate space (i think), so why is the size needed to declare one?
A non-array declaration works!

If you want to access arrya[2] then the compiler must use address array + 2*sizeof(array[0]). It can rely on the linker to find the address of array but not for the offset part.

i am not talking about using the array, but declaring it. The merely existence of such a declaration triggers a compiler error.

Why would it let you declare an array you can't use?

In your example it's not complaining about the array being an incomplete type, but the array element being one. That's a different story - you should edit your question. That is, extern int foos[]; compiles just fine and that's an array of incomplete type.

And well, isn't the question rather why C++ allows this? Btw struct Foo {}; is invalid C as well, so that would be the second compiler error in the C program. Use gcc in conforming C mode to get compiler reports regarding violations of the C language.

"Why does C not allow this?" Such question usually don't have answers because nobody can read minds of C standard committee members.

@ikegami "Why would it let you declare an array you can't use" The same can be asked about a struct. extern struct Foo foo; Why would it let you declare a struct you can't use? But this is a prerfectly valid declaration.

First of all, that's not equivalent. That's an incomplete type, but your question isn't about incomplete types. It's about arrays with elements of an incomplete type. /// Secondly, incomplete structures are allowed to provide a means of creating opaque types. You don't need two ways of doing that, especially when an array of elements of an incomplete type wouldn't even be completely opaque.

When you want to access an extern variable, its adress gets solved and replaced in your assembly at link time.
Accessing an array element requieres 2 things : the base adress, and the element-type size. For an array of well-known type such as int, both are not a problem when linking to an external variable. However, for a structured type, the size is not known at compile-time, and is not provided by the linker afterward. So C disallows the declaration of such an array.
However, I wonder why C++ allows this. Either the linker gives the later information, or this is unsafe dark magic from C++ again.

There is no "unsafe dark magic" in C++. There is your lack of knowledge of the language.

C++, as C is getting full of unsafe dark bad design choice in the language. You can not expect people to not complain about bad design by simply saying "hey, read the standard"
This is the may reason people are trying to find solutions for it in other languages, such as Rust, Zig, Go. To get rid of this pile of technical debt no-one can solve now.
Not saying it is the case here however.

The language is not the problem. Laziness is. People are lazy. They want quick results without spending much time, so they invent other languages instead of addressing the root of the problem, which is laziness.

BTW the reason the OP's code doesn't compile is because C is more strict with the order of declaration. See my comment to his question.

Well, what you are doing is totally compiler dependent, and in fact even disallowed by the C99 standard. see : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/755305/empty-structure-in-c
And you are basically declaring an empty struct, which is not at all what the OP asked for. He wants an array to an uncomplete type.
But I guess it's just "your lack of knowledge of the language" :)

"what you are doing is totally compiler dependent" I think you are misidentifying me with the OP. He's the one doing something that's compiler dependent, or more likely, he oversimplified his example and removed all struct members.

"in fact even disallowed by the C99 standard" It's not. It merely says that all objects must have size. So, you can interpret struct S { }; as having a size of 1, which is what C++ does.

I don't know if you even read the links I provide. You can not counter argument with simple "it's not"
See https://www.dii.uchile.cl/~daespino/files/Iso_C_1999_definition.pdf
Section 6.2.5-20 : "A structure type describes a sequentially allocated nonempty set of member objects
(and, in certain circumstances, an incomplete array), each of which has an optionally
specified name and possibly distinct type."

You are correct, but like I said earlier, you should take it up with the OP and not myself. I am not the one who came up with the empty struct. I merely copy-pasted it. For all I care he does have some members in the struct, but because they are irrelevant to his question, he removed them in his example. That's all.

You seem to be hell-bent on proving me wrong just because I've downvoted your answer. My only problem with your answer if the last sentence where you bad-mouth C++. If you can remove that sentence, I will retract my downvote.

The question is about declaring, not accessing. The OP is well aware that accessing the elements would be impossible. The OP made both of these things clear in the comments. This doesn't answer the question.

@Super-intelligentShade It is believed that no single person in the world can list all forms of poorly-defined behavior in C++. Not even WG21 as a group knows about it all. Unsafe dark magic is as good a name as any for these forms of poorly-defined behavior that nobody knows of. The cause of such unsafe dark magic is the extreme feature bloat that C++ suffers from far more so than any other language.

@Super-intelligentShade ""in fact even disallowed by the C99 standard" It's not". It is but it's not an easy find in the C standard, see Empty structure in C. Whereas C++ explicitly covers the empty struct/class scenario, as seen in one answer to that question.

@ikegami both are linked. If you can't access it, then why would the compiler let you declare it.

@PoneyUHC Private encapsulation is often implemented with forward declaration of an incomplete "opaque type" in C. The caller can't access the struct, only the implementation can. There are a few other scenarios as well.

It wouldn't be possible to access the array, so there's no point in allowing such a declaration. Not allowing it keeps the language simpler and helps catch errors sooner and more cleanly.
One might point out that it's possible to declare a struct that one can't access. The difference is that the allowance for incomplete structs serves a purpose, the creation of opaque types. There's no reason to provide a second way of doing this, and an array with elements of an incomplete struct wouldn't be (fully) opaque anyway!
This is by no means an official answer—the existing of one is very unlikely—but it would be a valid argument for leaving out the "feature" and a likely reason individuals might avoid bringing up requests for adding it.

The problem is not extern but the fact the compiler don't know what is struct Foo at that declaration.
You can check that easily with extern int fooo[];.
C and C++ is not the same language don't expect everything work the same.

You really missed the point. They are well aware that extern int a[] works. And you didn't answer the question (why isn't extern struct Incomplete a[]; allowed?)
