# Why is the size of an empty class in C++ not zero?

Tags: c++, sizeof

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [C++: What is the size of an object of an empty class?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/621616/c-what-is-the-size-of-an-object-of-an-empty-class)

Why does the following output `1`?

```
#include <iostream>

class Test
{
};

int main()
{
    std::cout << sizeof(Test);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: There is a dummy placeholder member whose size happens to be one byte. Since for an array of Test[10], each object should have a unique address.

Comment: An interesting optimization though is the `Empty Base Optimization`, meaning that if you inherit from an empty base class (no attribute, no virtual methods), then your class size won't grow. There are a number of (other) conditions, but it explains why privately inheriting from predicates in some situations.

Comment: [similar question 1](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1626446) and [similar question 2](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/621616/).

Answer (score 136, accepted):

The standard does not allow objects (and classes thereof) of size 0, since that would make it possible for two distinct objects to have the same memory address. That's why even empty classes must have a size of (at least) 1.

Comment: Hm... but shouldn't the linker be able to take care of that regardless of what sizeof() returns?  Isn't this more like a side-effect?  I understand what you are saying, but isn't it perfectly doable to return 0 for sizeof(Test). But if the standard says so, it says so. Actually a good thing for once to be explicit instead of intentionally vague about a subject.

Comment: @Amigable, so what would `Test a[10];` have as size? And `sizeof a / sizeof *a` would divide by 0. And `for(Test *i = a; i != a + 10; i++) f(i);` would also fail to work. I believe it would cause a lot of problems, as you need a lot of special cases in compilers *and* in user code.

Comment: @Johannes, so true. I did not think about that.

Comment: @JohannesSchaub-litb: I disagree with your comment. sizeof a / sizeof *a would be 0/0 which would be consistent and "proper" behavior for zero size types (this is because Test a[10] and Test a[100] can not be distinguished, which is logical since they are both degenerate}). Also the for loop would NOT fail. This is because a + 10  = a. I dont see any logical inconsistency with zero size types, IMO not allowing them introduces inconsistencies. The only advantage this has is probably just the requirement that all objects have distinct addresses.

Comment: @AndreasH.: I mostly agree with you, and I think `sizeof(Empty)` should have been zero. But it is a bit more complicated because `for(Test *i = a; i != a + 10; ++i) f(*i);` would do a different thing from `for(int i = 0; i < 10; ++i) f(a[i])`. I've analyzed it in detail, including a proposed solution, at [Legalization of empty objects](http://stannum.co.il/blog/4/legalization-of-empty-objects).

Answer (score 38):

> To ensure that the addresses of two
>   different objects will be different.
>   For the same reason, "new" always
>   returns pointers to distinct objects.

See [Stroustrup](http://www.stroustrup.com/bs_faq2.html#sizeof-empty) for complete answer.

Answer (score 31):

The C++ standard guarantees that the size of any class is at least one. The C++ standard states that no object shall have the same memory address as another object. There are several good reasons for this.

1. To guarantee that `new` will always return a pointer to a distinct memory address.
2. To avoid some divisions by zero. For instance, pointer arithmetics (many of which done automatically by the compiler) involve dividing by `sizeof(T)`.

Note however that it doesn't mean that an empty base-class will add 1 to the size of a derived class:

```
struct Empty { };

struct Optimized : public Empty {
    char c;
};

// sizeof(Optimized) == 1 with g++ 4.0.1
```

[Bjarne Stroustrup talks about this](http://www.stroustrup.com/bs_faq2.html#sizeof-empty) too.

Comment: What pointer arithmetic involves _dividing_ by `sizeof(T)`? I can't think of a single example. Plase add at least one example.

Comment: @MSalters: iterating over arrays of elements of type T.

Comment: @MSalters: subtraction of two pointers returns the number of elements, not the number of bytes, in between.

Comment: @Ben Voigt: good point, you're right. Iterating over an array just means _adding_ `sizeof(T)` bytes to a pointer, but a poitner difference internally will be calculated first as a byte difference.

Answer (score 13):

Class without any data members and member function such type of class is known as empty class. Size of object of empty class is always 1 byte.

When we create object of any class at that time object always gets 3 characteristics i.e.

1. State
2. Behaviour
3. Identity

When we create object of empty class at that time State of that object is nothing. Behaviour of that object is also nothing, but compiler assigns a unique address to that object.
Memory in Computer is always organized in the form of bytes and minimum memory available at object address location is 1 byte. That's why size of object of empty class is 1 byte.

Comment: if any one wanted to knw abt 3 charecteristics of an object i.e. 1)State 2)Behaviour 3)Identity then ask me

Answer (score 4):

What Maurits and Péter said.

It is interesting to note in this context that compilers can do empty base class optimization (EBCO):

```
#include <iostream>
struct Foo {};
struct Bar : Foo {};
int main () {
    std::cout << sizeof(Foo) << ',' << sizeof(Bar) << std::endl;        
}
```

This will probably print "1,1" if you compile and run it. See also [Vandevoorde/Josuttis 16.2](http://books.google.de/books?id=EotSAwuBkJoC&lpg=PA289&vq=EBCO&dq=faq&pg=PA289#v=snippet&q=EBCO&f=false%20%22empty%20base%20class%20optimization%22&pg=PA289#v=onepage&q=&f=false) on EBCO.