# C++: Virtual Inheritance

Tags: c++, virtual-inheritance

Consider the code below:

```
#...
class A {};
class B: public A{};
class C: virtual public A{};
class D: virtual public C{};
// No More Classes
...
int _tmain(int argc, _TCHAR* argv[]) {
 cout<<sizeof(A)<<" ";
 cout<<sizeof(B)<<" ";
 cout<<sizeof(C)<<" ";
 cout<<sizeof(D)<<".";

 ...
}
```

O/P: 1 1 4 8.

Question:

1. sizeof(A) = 1byte, and this location hold what significant for compiler/us.
2. Why compiler bother to add vptr in C class object when there is nothing actually resides.
3. If we are not having any virtual function, compiler is adding an extra vptr to derived objects.

*. its' my 1st question here, please correct me if you found anything wrong.

Comment: For a first question here: +1 for a good, well formatted and self-explanatory post.

Comment: I don't really see any questions, just a list of statements.

Comment: @JoachimPileborg - "2. Why compiler bother to add vptr in C class object when there is nothing actually resides". I guess `3.` is the same as `.2`. And `1.` is most likely - showing that the OP knows why the result is `1`.

Comment: excellent and interesting first question

Comment: @meh A question usually ends with a question mark (like this one `?`). The code is not full (ie doesn't compile), and with window's extensions. Therefore, I wouldn't call it a well formatted and self-explanatory post.

Comment: @BЈовић - I also wrote "for a first question here". Most of the "first" questions here are much, much worse than this one, aren't they?

Answer (score 8):

In short it's not due to the class being virtual or not, it's because the standard requires that all objects be distinguishable by their memory address. See this question:

[Why is the size of an empty class in C++ not zero?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2362097/why-is-the-size-of-an-empty-class-in-c-not-zero)

Answer (score 0):

ad 1. See [PeddleSpam's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14724349/341065)

ad 2. IIRC the compiler puts more information than just virtual functions pointers into the so called VMT. One more information is the position of the virtual A in C, I think.

ad 3. See 2.