# why the size of the C++ class with enumerations declared is 1?

Tags: c++, class, memory, enums

```
class test
{
public:
    enum t_number
    {
        ZERO,
        ONE
    };

    enum t_test
    {
        TWO,
        THREE
    };
};
```

Why the size of the above class is 1 and not 8?

And when I do this in main()

```
cout << "value of enum"<< test::ONE
```

I get output as 1.

Does that mean memory is allocated for the enum?

Comment: Because you declared only types in your class (no members) and the minimum size of a class is 1.

Comment: Because you don't have any member variables. An object still needs to take some place, to be addressable, so it still is one single byte so it could be stored in memory.

Comment: You are not declaring data members...

Comment: Why would it be 8? It contains no data. C++ doesn't allow 0 size objects (because that would lead to various bad things like multiple objects having the same address and arrays behaving super weird), so 1 is the ideal choice.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Why is the size of an empty class in C++ not zero?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2362097/why-is-the-size-of-an-empty-class-in-c-not-zero)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Only data have size, you're not setting data in your class, you're defining types of data.

For the second part, recently added, you're asking to display test::ONE, like in C, enums are an abstraction of unsigned integers, so when you type :

```
enum foo {
    bar,
    baz,
    qux
};
```

It's exactly the same as typing

```
enum foo {
    bar = 0,
    baz = 1,
    qux = 2
};
```

So when you type this in your main

```
cout << "value of enum"<< test::ONE;
```

You just implicitely converting your test::ONE in its integer value.

Note that this implicit conversion would not exist with enum class in c++11.

Comment: To be fair, types have a size as well. You can query the size of a type and get a meaningful answer.

Comment: You mean to say "only data occupies storage". And even that can have exceptions.