# Why is stack memory allocated when it is not used?

Tags: c++, code-generation, calling-convention, abi, stack-allocation

Consider the following example:

```
struct vector {
    int  size() const;
    bool empty() const;
};

bool vector::empty() const
{
    return size() == 0;
}
```

The generated assembly code for `vector::empty` (by clang, with optimizations):

```
push    rax
call    vector::size() const
test    eax, eax
sete    al
pop     rcx
ret
```

Why does it allocate stack space? It is not used at all. The `push` and `pop` could be omitted. Optimized builds of MSVC and gcc also use stack space for this function (see on [godbolt](https://godbolt.org/z/ubvuDx)), so there must be a reason.

Comment: Did you account for the implicit `this` parameter?

Comment: @dan04: I did. `this` is passed in `rcx` register in MSVC and in `rdi` in clang and gcc. See this [example](https://godbolt.org/z/9kjVMG). It does not need stack.

Comment: Have you tried with an actually defined `vector::size()` function?

Comment: @Bob__: No. Why should I? `vector::size()` is not defined in the example to simuate that it is not inlined.

Comment: So, how could a compiler optimize something it doesn't know?

Comment: @Bob__: I think, that knowing the implementation of `vector::size()` is not relevant for allocating or not allocating a stack frame for `vector::empty()`. In `empty()` it is just called, whatever it is.

Comment: Well, you are calling a function that *returns* something, you need space for that (if you don't know any better).

Comment: @Bob__: Return value is in `eax`. No stack needed for that.

Comment: The `push` and `pop` could not be omitted, because they don't use the same register.

Comment: @MarkRansom: So any idea why they are there? They don't seem to accomplish much, except to preserve the value of `rax` but move it to `rcx`.

Comment: @FredLarson: these are just "dummy" stack aligment instructions. They are shorter than the equivalent `add rsp`-like instructions. Register doesn't matter here. For `pop`, `rcx` is used, because it can be trashed.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2362097/why-is-the-size-of-an-empty-class-in-c-not-zero

Answer (score 12, accepted):

It allocates stack space, so the stack is 16-byte aligned. It is needed, because the return address takes 8 bytes, so an additional 8-byte space is needed to keep the stack 16-byte aligned.

The alignment of stack frames can be configured with command line arguments for some compilers.

- **MSVC**: The [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/build/stack-usage?view=vs-2019) says that the stack is always 16-byte aligned. No [command line argument](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/build/reference/compiler-options-listed-alphabetically?view=vs-2019) can change this. The godbolt example shows that 40 bytes are subtracted from `rsp` at the beginning of the function, which means that something else also affects this.
- **clang**: The [`-mstack-alignment`](https://clang.llvm.org/docs/ClangCommandLineReference.html#cmdoption-clang-mstack-alignment) option specifies the stack alignment. It seems, that the default is 16, although not documented. If you set it to 8, the stack allocation (`push` and `pop`) disappears from the generated assembly code.
- **gcc**: The [`-mpreferred-stack-boundary`](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/x86-Options.html#x86-Options) option specifies the stack alignment. If the given value is N, it means 2^N bytes of alignment. The default value is 4, which means 16 bytes. If you set it to 3 (i.e. 8 bytes), the stack allocation (`sub` and `add` for `rsp`) disappears from the generated assembly code.

Check out on [godbolt](https://godbolt.org/z/augsYz).

Comment: That's why c++ gurus, experts have always been warning: put struct/class members in order of the longest/biggest size to smallest... only this way it'd be correctly efficient

Comment: @geza: Thank you. I did some research for the other two compilers, and written it to your answer. Do you like it?

Comment: @Dr.Gut: thanks, you made the answer much better and complete. Note, that stack alignment is usually documented in the ABI for the system (for example, for some systems, here are the documents: https://github.com/hjl-tools/x86-psABI/wiki/X86-psABI).

Comment: @geza: Thank you.