# empty struct definitions illegal in C but not C++?

Tags: c++, c, struct

```
struct t_empty {
};
```

This appears to compile properly in C++ but not C. (at least with the TI 28xx DSP compiler, where it emits the error "expected a declaration") Is this mentioned somewhere in the C standards, or is my compiler broken?

Comment: It compiles fine using gcc 4.2...

Comment: See for See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1626446/what-is-the-size-of-an-empty-struct-in-c for the discussion concerning C

Comment: one of comments from that link: "Empty structs are a GCC extension.". Thanks :)

Comment: @Artefacto: why did you delete your post? :-( it was useful.

Comment: @Jason S: It was wrong. The accepted answer in http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1626446/what-is-the-size-of-an-empty-struct-in-c gets it right.

Comment: A question for SO readers: given that gcc (wrongly) accepts this syntax, has anyone actually found a use for this extension in their code?

Comment: The situation that produced my question was a piece of code emitted by a code-generation tool. It defines a structure based on some metadata described elsewhere. The metadata in question was empty.

Comment: @AndreyT honestly when i wrote my answer to the other question i wasn't *really* sure about it (i worded my answer carefully to avoid saying wrong things), since in C you can cause undefined behavior but still guaranteed to receive diagnostics (unlike in C++). But now i'm actually sure that behavior is not undefined for `struct A { };` - it's just a syntax violation, because there is no empty `struct-declaration-list`. After diagnosing a non-conforming program the implementation can do anything it likes anyway, so it doesn't really matter whether the semantic constraint still applies or not :)

Comment: However it *does* matter that the syntax violation applies, since it determines whether a diagnostic is required or not :) So i too think that missing to say it's a syntax violation in an answer makes an answer wrong, i think.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Empty struct is a syntax error in C. The grammar of C language is written so that it prohibits empty structs. I.e. you won't find it stated in the standard explicitly, it just follows from the grammar.

In C++ empty classes are indeed legal.

P.S. Note, that often you might see the quote from the C standard that says *"If the struct-declaration-list contains no named members, the behavior is undefined."*, which is presented as the portion of the document that prohibits empty structs. In reality, empty structs are, again, prohibited by the grammar. So a literally empty struct (as in your question) is a syntax error, not undefined behavior. The above quote from the standard applies to a different situation: a struct with *no named members*. A struct can end up non-empty, but at the same time with no named members if all members are unnamed bitfields

```
struct S {
  int : 5;
};
```

In the above case the behavior is undefined. This is what the above quote is talking about.