# sizeof empty structure is 0 in C and 1 in C++ why?

Tags: c++, c, struct, sizeof

> **Possible Duplicates:**
> [Empty class in C++](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2362097/empty-class-in-c)
> [What is the size of an empty struct in C?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1626446/what-is-the-size-of-an-empty-struct-in-c)

I read somewhere that size of an empty struct in C++ is 1. So I thought of verifying it.
Unfortunately I saved it as a C file and used `<stdio.h>` header and I was surprised to see the output. It was 0.

That means

```
struct Empty {

};

int main(void)
{
  printf("%d",(int)sizeof(Empty));
}
```

was printing `0` when compiled as a C file and `1` when compiled as a C++ file. I want to know the reason. I read that `sizeof` empty struct in C++ is not zero because if the size were `0` then two objects of the class would have the same address which is not possible. Where am I wrong?

Comment: -1 No, you didn't compile that as `C`.

Comment: @Ninad : Did you try [this](http://ideone.com/WAxMI)?

Comment: When you're asking questions at this level of language please include the compiler name and version.

Comment: This is a super-duplicate. For C, duplicate of [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1626446/what-is-the-size-of-an-empty-struct-in-c) (answer: it's ill-formed). In C++, [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2362097/empty-class-in-c) (answer: it must have  a size greater than zero so space can be allocated for it).

Comment: @GMan : Oh damn! I thought it was really a good question, dupe though :) Thanks for the links.

Comment: -1 by me too. the sizeof cannot compile

Comment: Why don't post an answer explaining it instead of downvoting?

Comment: @chakrit i like to post answers to actual questions.

Comment: @chakrit: duplicate questions do not warrant any answer, they just need be redirected to their doppleganger.

Answer (score 22):

You cannot have an empty structure in C. It is a syntactic constraint violation. 
However gcc permits an empty structure in C [as an extension](http://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Empty-Structures.html).
Furthermore the behaviour is **undefined** if the structure does not have any named member because

`C99` says :

> If the struct-declaration-list contains no named members, the behavior is undefined.

So

```
struct Empty {}; //constraint violation

struct Empty {int :0 ;}; //no named member, the behaviour is undefined.
```

And yes size of an empty struct is C++ [cannot be zero](http://www.stroustrup.com/bs_faq2.html#sizeof-empty) :)

Answer (score 7):

There are several good reasons. Among others, this is to ensure that pointer arithmetics over pointers to that structure don't lead to an infinite loop. More information:

http://bytes.com/topic/c/insights/660463-sizeof-empty-class-structure-1-a

Answer (score 6):

Here is a wonderful article describing why this occurs, and more pertinently, a (safe) way around it :)

http://www.cantrip.org/emptyopt.html