# How does repr(C) behave on a zero sized type in Rust?

Tags: c, rust

I've came across [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3849334/sizeof-empty-structure-is-0-in-c-and-1-in-c-why) that explains that structs in C can't be zero-sized and must have at least one named field to not be undefined behavior. However, in Rust, we can have such structs. And we can also mark structs as `#[repr(C)]` that will, from [the docs](https://doc.rust-lang.org/nomicon/other-reprs.html), "do what C does".

So naturally, I went out to the playground to try [this](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2021&gist=cf0a089624e299ff8272a59fc564e934):

```rust
#[repr(C)]
struct ZeroSized;

fn main() {
    println!("Size: {}", std::mem::size_of::<ZeroSized>());
}
```

And this code does print out 0.

I was wondering does Rust allows `#[repr(C)]` zero sized structs if they are forbidden, and even UB, in C? Will the final size of such a struct actually be 0? What would happen if I copy this struct around in memory? Can I even have a pointer to it?

Comment: The question is interesting, but I cannot imagine any real situation where we would have to share a ZST between Rust and C. Could you suggest an example?

Answer (score 6):

I suggest you read further in the [documentation on repr](https://doc.rust-lang.org/nomicon/other-reprs.html)

> ZSTs are still zero-sized, even though this is not a standard behavior in C, and is explicitly contrary to the behavior of an empty type in C++, which says they should still consume a byte of space.

To answer your questions:

> I was wondering does Rust allows #[repr(C)] zero sized structs if they are forbidden, and even UB, in C? Will the final size of such a struct actually be 0?

Yes, and yes, see above.

> What would happen if I copy this struct around in memory?

As with any ZST the compiler will most likely [omit the copies](https://rust.godbolt.org/z/zv9EaMc97)

> Can I even have a pointer to it?

As with any ZST [yes](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2021&gist=466663d74efa7f9aabbc4cbe259ec6d2).

Comment: This goes for rust side of things, but trying to read a pointer to a rust ZST from C is likely to be an UB, as far as I understand?

Comment: @IvanC If it points to a ZST, yes. If it doesn't, and it's just that its type is of a pointer to ZST, then it's fine to read it (with its actual type).