# Struct with no member

Tags: c, struct, linux-kernel

While refering kernel code [here](http://lxr.free-electrons.com/source/arch/arm/mm/vmregion.h?v=3.4;a=arm#L7), `struct page;` is defined with no member(I Guess this is not a forward declaration).

But the accepted answer in [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1626446/what-is-the-size-of-an-empty-struct-in-c) post says it is not allowed.

Then i tried a sample,

```
#include <stdio.h>

struct page;

struct arm_vmregion 
{
   unsigned long           vm_start;
   unsigned long           vm_end;
   struct page             *vm_pages;
   int                     vm_active;
   const void              *caller;
};

int main()
{
   struct arm_vmregion aa;
   return 0;
}
```

It compiles successfully

```
empty_struct.c: In function ‘main’:
empty_struct.c:15:22: warning: unused variable ‘aa’ [-Wunused-variable]
```

Please clarify me in this regard.

Comment: It *is* a forward declaration.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

An empty struct is not the same as a forward declaration - an empty struct would have braces, and would not be legal. Forward declarations are fine of course.

```
struct foo;    // forward declaration - OK

struct bar {   // empty struct - invalid
};
```

Answer (score 0):

It is a forward decl, here is where it is defined:

http://lxr.free-electrons.com/source/include/linux/mm_types.h?v=3.4