# Difference between sizeof(empty struct) and sizeof(struct with empty array)?

Tags: c++, c, struct, sizeof

I have two structs defined as follows:

```
struct EmptyStruct{

};

struct StructEmptyArr{
    int arr[0];
};

int main(void){
    printf("sizeof(EmptyStruct) = %ld\n", sizeof(EmptyStruct));
    printf("sizeof(StructEmptyArr) = %ld\n", sizeof(StructEmptyArr));

    return 0;
}
```

Compiled with gcc (g++) 4.8.4 on Ubuntu 14.04, x64.

Output (for both gcc and g++):

```
sizeof(EmptyStruct) = 1
sizeof(StructEmptyArr) = 0
```

I can understand why `sizeof(EmptyStruct)` equals to `1` but cannot understand why `sizeof(StructEmptyArr)` equals to `0`. Why are there differences between two?

Comment: The latter is not a valid struct, so the compiler makes up a value of its own by adding features to the c++ language. The idea probably is that sizeof(struct)+sizeof(array) will yield a pointer just past the array and (char*)structpointer+sizeof(struct) gives the first element of the array.

Comment: Related to: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1626446/what-is-the-size-of-an-empty-struct-in-c, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9722632/what-happens-if-i-define-a-0-size-array-in-c-c

Comment: Interesting, because I just did this with gcc version 6.3.0 and got an output of 0 for both.

Comment: And I did it again with g++ (same version of 6.3.0) and got sizeof 1 for the empty struct and sizeof 0 for the struct with a 0 size array.

Comment: I suggest looking at the assembly code

Comment: For C++ see: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9722632/what-happens-if-i-define-a-0-size-array-in-c-c

Comment: Sum up so far: for C, `EmptyStruct` causes UB; for C++, `StructEmptyArr` causes UB. Am I correct?

Comment: @duong_dajgja: For standard C, `StructEmptyArr` is a syntax error (there must be at least one member in the structure C11 §6.7.2.1 ¶2), as is `EmptyStruct` (zero size arrays are not permitted in standard C; C11 §6.7.6.2 ¶1).  GCC has extensions that may make them acceptable, but the standard says "No".

Comment: @mgarey I suspect this won't actually help, the compiler (should) will replace the sizeof call with a literal value matching that printed out.

Comment: In passing: the result of `sizeof` operator is a size_t, so you should be using `%zu` or similar, not `%ld`.

Comment: gcc and g++ will whinge about the zero-size array, if you ask it to: `gcc -std=c11 -Wall -Wextra -Wpedantic` or `g++ -std=c++17 -Wall -Wextra -Wpedantic`.

Answer (score 40, accepted):

In C, the behavior of a program is undefined if a struct is defined without any named member.

C11-§6.7.2.1:

> If the struct-declaration-list does not contain any named members, either directly or via an anonymous structure or anonymous union, the behavior is undefined.

GCC allows an empty struct as [an extension](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc-4.1.2/gcc/Empty-Structures.html#Empty-Structures) and its size will be `0`.

---

For C++, [the standard doesn't allow an object of size `0`](http://www.stroustrup.com/bs_faq2.html#sizeof-empty) and therefore `sizof(EmptyStruct)`  returns a value of 1.
Arrays of zero length are not supported by standard C++¹, but are [supported as an extension by GNU](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc-4.4.4/gcc/Zero-Length.html) and the `sizeof` operator will return `0` if applied.

---

<sub>1. § 8.5.1-footnote 107) C++ does not have zero length arrays.</sub>

Comment: But he says that he understands the reason for why the empty struct has its size. And the struct that *does* have a named member has the confusing size.

Comment: @michael clearly the code is not ISO C, because he uses the tag withithout the tag namespace qualifier

Comment: @JohannesSchaub-litb That's moot, I answered a direct question above

Comment: @michael it is not moot because while apples are red, my shirt is blue and in ISO C structs must have a named member, none of this is relevant because the question is not about apples, ISO C, or my shirt

Comment: Please see the comment above by PasserBy, that is the question I was answering.

Comment: @duong_dajgja; Updated the answer.

Comment: I must say that your description is incorrect. Since we are in pedantry mode, I must note that c++ allows objects of size 0

Comment: @JohannesSchaub-litb; [Its not my hypothesis](http://www.stroustrup.com/bs_faq2.html#sizeof-empty). Also: *"Unless it is a bit-field (9.6), a most derived object shall have a non-zero size and shall occupy one or more
bytes of storage. **Base class subobjects may have zero size**."*  § 1.8 (p5)

Comment: @hacks you say that the standard forbids objects of size 0, and go on to quote that it allows such. And link to a page that merely says that objects shall have different addresses. If I take numbers 9+0 and 8+0, both are different, yet I added 0 to them.

Comment: @JohannesSchaub-litb; It also says *a most derived object shall have a non-zero size and shall occupy one or more bytes of storage*.

Answer (score 5):

https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Empty-Structures.html

> G++ treats empty structures as if they had a single member of type char.

https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Zero-Length.html

> Zero-length arrays are allowed in GNU C. They are very useful as the last element of a structure that is really a header for a variable-length object.