# sizeof(blank class) == 1. why?

Tags: c++

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [C++: What is the size of an object of an empty class?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/621616/c-what-is-the-size-of-an-object-of-an-empty-class)

```
#include <iostream>

class C
{
};

int main()
{
    std::cout << sizeof(C) << std::endl;

    return 0;
}
```

output:
  1

Why 1, but not zero ?

Answer (score 5):

From Stroustrup's mouth  [sizeof. To ensure that the addresses of two different objects will be different. For the same reason, "new" always returns pointers to distinct objects.](http://www2.research.att.com/~bs/bs_faq2.html#sizeof-empty)

Answer (score 4):

Because the C++ standard requires all objects to have a nonzero size.  This helps ensure that every object has a unique address.

Comment: Can you quote a reference. I ask because I thought the standard says that each object must have a unique address. The easy way for the compiler to guarantee this is to make each object have a size of at least one. But I could be wrong.

Answer (score 1):

The c++ standard says that every class/struct must have at least 1 byte.

Comment: Not universally true. Only most derived objects need have non-zero size. Instances of classes that are base class subobjects may have zero size.

Comment: Base class is part of derived class, as a whole they must have at least 1 byte. You cannot divide an object to derived/base parts, all belong to one class - derived.

Comment: Lets talk about objects, not classes. A base class subobject is part of a more derived object but you can and people frequently do divide it into base and derived types. If you pass a derived object into a function taking a reference to the base class then what is visible in the function is the base class part of the derived object. From the standard: "Base class subobjects may have zero size.". I think that's pretty clear.

Comment: If you cast to a sub-object, it still has at least 1 byte. Maybe wiser would be say that if this 1 byte is not used by an empty base class it can be used by derived class.