# Questions about C++ virtual Inheritance

Tags: c++, inheritance, virtual

The following code are from the book "Inside the C++ object model"

```
#include <iostream>  
using namespace std;
class X{};
class Y: public virtual X{};
class Z: public virtual X{};
class A: public Y, public Z{};

int main()
{
     cout<<sizeof(X)<<" "<<sizeof(Y)<<" "<<sizeof(Z)<<" "<<sizeof(A)<<endl;
     return 0;
}
```

In my computer(Windows, VS2010), the output is:

1 4 4 8

Here're my questions

1, sizeof(X)=1

The book says when X type generate two instance, say xa and xb. the compile insert a byte into A so that xa and xb can have different address. I'm not quite understand the reasons.

2, sizeof(Y)=4

By using virtual inheritance, will we have an additional virtual pointer? I guess this might be different from virtual pointer in polymorphism. Can anyone give me the memory layout for Y?

Thank you!

Comment: One question per question please

Comment: for the 1st question, check: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/621616/c-what-is-the-size-of-an-object-of-an-empty-class?rq=1

Comment: I think your main question is that because Y uses virtual inheritence to derive from a non-polymorphic class X, and Y itself is non-polymorphic, will the virutal inheritence itself cause Y to have a v-table thus its size being 4..

Answer (score 6, accepted):

1. compiler new one char when the class is empty, so it can generate different object
2. sizeof(Y)=4 because it's virtual inheritance, construct will generate vptr table which is 4 bytes on 32-bit system
3. if you are using visual studio use /d1reportAllClassLayout in properties->C/C++/Command to generate object layout
   class Y object layout will be on Visual Studio:
4. book 'Inside C++ object model' by Stanley B. Lippman explained this extremely well

```
 
        class Y size(4):
            +---
            0     | {vbptr}
            +---
            +--- (virtual base X)
            +---

      Y::$vbtable@:
       0    | 0
       1    | 4 (Yd(Y+0)X)
```

vbi:     class  offset o.vbptr  o.vbte fVtorDisp
        X       4       0       4     0

Answer (score 1):

sizeof of an empty class always returns 1. Thats a single dummy byte for an empty class.

A holds the two entries in the virtual table, 
one for Y 
other for Z

So the sizeof two pointers i.e. 8.

Y and Z hold both have a single entry of X in their virtual table, hence the size is 4.

Comment: I don't see classes called B and C here

Answer (score 1):

An A object will include an Y object, a Z object (in that order) and only *one* X Object (referenced by pointers in Y and Z), because both Y and Z inherit virtually from X, thus meaning that when multiple inheritance comes to play only one X object will be instantiatet within the child-classes. A still has two objects (one Y, one Z) and thus has sizeof = 8 (since they both have sizeof = 4). But both pointers in Y and Z to the X object will point to the same address.

The inheritance tree will look like:

```
  X
 / \
 Y Z
 \ /
  A
```

Answer (score 0):

The reason classes -must- be at least 1 byte is say we have an array of X. If they were 0 bytes then &array[1] would have the same address as &array[3] which no one would expect, would break code, be annoying if you had to write code to check for that and typically won't make any sense.

Y would simply be

```
static void* virtual_ptr1 //note this is in virtual table and cannot be edited
```

You can think of vtables (virtual pointers to classes and virtual functions) as static variables that you can not edit by hand/code (or at least should not). Think of it as compiler reserved static variables

Comment: I like this explanation for the reason sizeof(X)=1