# size of empty structure in C and C++

Tags: c++, c

Sizeof  empty struct is 0 byte in C but in C++ it is 1 byte. Why? What's the difference?

Comment: What's the difference? They're different languages.

Comment: ok! But new features of C is nothing but C++ Correct! if it is different language means how the header files are supported of c in C++? There is a similarity b/w two languages. but why it is 0 byte in C?

Comment: @Ramakrishna: Simple: not all C header files are supported in C++.

Answer (score 10):

In `C` its not correct, you cannot have a `struct` without a member in it.

`C99 says`,

> If the struct-declaration-list contains no named members, the behavior is undefined.

However `GCC` allows you to have a no member struct with size being `0`. `G++` treats struct as if it has a single member of type `char` in it.

Look at this previous [SO answering](https://stackoverflow.com/q/621616/1079907) why in C++ the size is `1B`.

Comment: Clang will also print 1 byte if you apply `sizeof()` in an empty struct (should be same for a class).