# Clang-tidy alignment suggestion with `altera-struct-pack-align`

Tags: c++, alignment, memory-alignment, clang-tidy

I am experimenting with clang-tidy (while using a gcc) with all of it's checks. I was curious if the below case is a bug of clang-tidy as it contradicts my compiler's  warnings. Here is a minimum example:

```cpp
struct a{
    virtual void func()=0;
    virtual void func2()=0;
}; 
struct b:a{
    void func() override {};
    void func2() override {};
private: 
   int x{};
    
}
int main(){
    b b_item;
}
```

The suggestion :

```
/home/main.cpp:7:8: note: use "__attribute__((aligned(0)))" to align struct 'a' to 0 bytes
struct a{
       ^
/home/main.cpp:13:8: warning: accessing fields in struct 'b' is inefficient due to padding; only needs 4 bytes but is using 16 bytes [altera-struct-pack-align]
struct b:a{
       ^
```

I will not demonstrate the code after the suggestion as clang-tidy made a lot of changes the important bit is:

```
struct a{
    virtual void func()=0;
    virtual void func2()=0;
} __attribute__((aligned(0)));
```

warning after calling fix:

```
warning: requested alignment ‘0’ is not a positive power of 2 [-Wattributes]
   12 | } __attribute__((aligned(0)));
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Reasoning

After all the reasoning for that is quite simple. The `altera*` options of clang-tidy relate with fpga programming in C with some very specific compilers  in mind (I think altera uses [c2h](https://www.intel.com/content/dam/www/programmable/us/en/pdfs/literature/ug/ug_nios2_c2h_compiler.pdf) and there is also a big list of alternatives [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5603285/c-to-hardware-compiler-hll-synthesis)). These compilers probably doesn't have these quite advanced warning but I haven't verified that yet. A reason I believe that is that c lang doesn't have virtual functions so I can not think of a case where zero byte alignment would be appropriate([C doesn't allow trivial structs](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21851930/size-of-empty-structure-in-c-and-c/21851976#:%7E:text=Sizeof%20empty%20struct%20is%200,C%2B%2B%20it%20is%201%20byte.)).

### Aftermath

The question that occurred to me is why gcc throws these warning? Is it appropriate to have a zero byte struct in c++ ?
The answer is no pure virtual and abstract classes never compile they are only used as base classes for others. Structs like the `struct a` in my question never appear in assembly. So as a conclusion I believe that both gcc and clang-tidy are correct on their warnings but I would strongly recommend to someone to not use clang-tidy fpga specific flags on non-fpga projects.[Here](https://gcc.gnu.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=69089) and [here](https://gcc.gnu.org/git/?p=gcc.git&a=commit;h=673670da1e5dae2aaccbade88d540cf0200f0eb3) is some reasoning on gcc side about introducing these warning.