# D: What will s refer to in foreach(ref s; sections[0..$/2+1])

Tags: foreach, d, slice

What are the indices these two foreach loops will iterate over:

```
struct Section{}
Section[] sections;

// assuming we have 10 sections
foreach(ref s; sections[0..$/2+1]) {
    // do something
}       

foreach_reverse(ref s; sections[$/2..$])
{
    // do something
}
```

Comment: Well, I was answering the "what will s refer to..." as the title says. Please change the title if you don't mean to ask that.

Comment: What would your advice be for a better title?

Comment: The first sentence of your question? If that's what you are interested in.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

the first will iterate over `0-sections.length/2+1=6` (exclusive) and the second will iterate `10-5`

the `$` in the index refers to the length of the array

and the `array[a..b]` notation expands to `array.opSlice(a,b)` that returns a partial view of the array

Comment: I get 0..$/2, but what is the effect of the +1? Thanks.

Comment: Good explanation, thanks. I wonder though how d will behave if length is odd, say 9. Will it be 0-ceil(sections.length/2)+1=6 ?

Comment: no integer divide will `floor` (more accurately it will cut of the fractional part)

Comment: Thanks alot. One thing is disturbing me though.. foreach_reverse(ref s; sections[$/2..$]). Wouldn`t that be 10-5 not 5-10?

Comment: ah yes I've been a bit hasty in answering it seems

Answer (score 1):

In D, an empty struct has a size 1. The rationale is the same as in C++: see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/621616/c-what-is-the-size-of-an-object-of-an-empty-class) for a relevant question and the rationale. So, your array will contain dummy 1-byte elements.

Let us check this behavior:

```
import std.stdio;

struct Section{}
Section[] sections = new Section [10];

void main () {
    foreach(ref s; sections[0..$/2+1]) {
        writeln (&s);
    }
}
```

To me, this prints:

```
42208C
42208D
42208E
42208F
422090
422091
```

which are consecutive addresses in memory.