# I don't understand why 'Derived1' requires the same amount of memory as 'Derived3'

Tags: c++, oop

In the following code I don't understand why 'Derived1' requires the same amount of memory as 'Derived3'. Also is there any specific significance of size of Derived 4 being 16.

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

class Empty
{};

class Derived1 : public Empty
{};

class Derived2 : virtual public Empty
{};

class Derived3 : public Empty
{    
    char c;
};

class Derived4 : virtual public Empty
{
    char c;
};

class Dummy
{
    char c;
};

int main()
{
    cout << "sizeof(Empty) " << sizeof(Empty) << endl;
    cout << "sizeof(Derived1) " << sizeof(Derived1) << endl;
    cout << "sizeof(Derived2) " << sizeof(Derived2) << endl;
    cout << "sizeof(Derived3) " << sizeof(Derived3) << endl;
    cout << "sizeof(Derived4) " << sizeof(Derived4) << endl;    
    cout << "sizeof(Dummy) " << sizeof(Dummy) << endl;

    return 0;
}
```

The output of this code gave was:

```
sizeof(Empty) 1
sizeof(Derived1) 1
sizeof(Derived2) 8
sizeof(Derived3) 1
sizeof(Derived4) 16
sizeof(Dummy) 1
```

Comment: Google "Empty base optimisation"

Comment: An object cannot have a size of `0`, in other words it needs to have an address. Therefore even the "empty" classes need at least one byte. Therefore the classes that add a single `char` handle that requirement, so you don't need a "dummy" byte for the empty base class anymore after that.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [C++: What is the size of an object of an empty class?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/621616/c-what-is-the-size-of-an-object-of-an-empty-class)

Comment: @NickyC The question you mentioned didn't really cover my doubt entirely. Thanks for the suggestion anyway

Answer (score 8):

A `class` must have a `sizeof` of 1 or greater otherwise pointer arithmetic would break horribly, and the elements of array of that `class` would all occupy the same memory.

So `sizeof(Derived1)` is at least 1, as is `sizeof(Empty)`. *Empty base optimisation* means that the size of the derived class is effectively zero.

`sizeof(Derived3)` can also be 1, since the single member is a `char`. Note that the compiler is again exploiting *empty base optimisation* here.

The *polymorphic* classes (i.e. those containing `virtual` keywords), have larger sizes due to your compiler implementing the requirements for polymorphic behaviour.

Answer (score 2):

> In the following code I don't understand why 'Derived1' requires the same amount of memory as 'Derived3'.

Unlike all other objects, empty base-sub-objects are allowed to share their address with their sibling objects. Therefore an empty base does not need to occupy any memory whatsoever.

Besides the **empty** base, `Derived3` contains nothing more than a `char` object. The size of `char` is 1, so `Derived3` fits within the size of 1.

Besides the **empty** base, `Derived1` contains nothing. But because all objects (excluding exceptions involving sub-objects) must have a unique address, the minimum size of any type is 1. Therefore the size of `Derived1` is 1.

> Also is there any specific significance of size of Derived 4 being 16.

No significance whatsoever. The size is quite typical.