# Why c++ empty class have no byte alignment？

Tags: c++, memory, alignment, sizeof, empty-class

I recently learned that empty class have size 1 instead of zero.Why it has no byte alignment, in which 
 it's size should be 4 in 32bit environment? What's the address of the next object?

Comment: why do you think it should have alignment 4?

Comment: The "next object" doesn't mean anything unless the object in question is part of an array or inside a `struct`.

Comment: Does this answer your questoin: [What is the size of an object of an empty class?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/621616/c-what-is-the-size-of-an-object-of-an-empty-class).

Comment: @bolov -- because in a 32-bit environment, pretty much everything does.

Comment: @PeteBecker no it doesn't https://godbolt.org/z/CkQmMc

Comment: Wow, fundamental logic, folks: "pretty much everything does" is **not** asserting that **everything** does.

Comment: @PeteBecker I don't understand your point. In x86-32 usually objects 4 bytes or larger have 4 byte alignment and objects smaller have alignment equal to their size. So that's why I asked why does the OP thinks an object with size 1 should have an alignment of 4.

Comment: @bolov: An object with size 1 **cannot** have alignment 4. Consider an array of them.

Comment: @bolov unless you #pragma pack(1) your structs will almost certainly align every member at a 4 byte boundary regardless of its size

Comment: @bolov -- the point is that you asked "why do you think...", and I took a stab at answering **that question** -- why would a beginner think that things are all aligned at 4 bytes. I'll bet that at one point in your life you, too, were confused about things that you now take for granted. Demanding explanations for things like that is simply hostile. Granted, it's common here, but it's still hostile.

Comment: @PeteBecker I wasn't hostile. The point of my question was to understand what assumptions/misconceptions the OP has so that we can address them.

Comment: @BitTemp Sorry but it's totally untrue. Try to inspect addresses of members of an object of type `struct X { char a, b, c, d; };`. All the members will be very likely 1-byte distant.

Comment: What is _no byte alignment_?

Comment: @BigTemp : Daniel is right, that's not the case. Maybe if you allocate memory for it, individually, on the heap.

Comment: @DanielLangr Oops. I worded that sentence wrong. Yeah 4 consecutive chars will most likely be treated as a char array[4] but the moment you try introducing a larger type like `struct Y { char a; long long b; bool c; double d; };` you will get some sort of padding. On Intel C++ in x64 mode the struct and its members will all be aligned at an 8 byte boundary.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Because C++ simply does not guarantee 4-byte alignment, or word-alignment, of variables. If this is important to you, you can specify an alignment requirement using [`alignas`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/alignas):

```
struct alignas(4) my_empty_struct {};
```

and now, the address of a `my_empty_struct` variable would be a multiple of 4 - and [so will its size, apparently](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61856747/).

Alternatively, you could pad your struct with a dummy field for alignment, yourself. The `alignas` is a bit like padding with an inaccessible field.

Comment: `sizeof(my_empty_struct)` gives 4 to me though.

Comment: @Waqar: It varies, but it's never 0.

Comment: Thanks, @Waqar, I didn't realize that could be the case.