# C++ Key Value Relationship

Tags: c++

I want to store the combination of X, Y and distance in a data structure.
where X and Y are integers.
distance is the distance between X and Y.

Which would be the best data structure to use in c++ so that I can later find if the combination is present in the list?

Comment: What list? Please give more context

Comment: He means key, value relationships. I have a pending title edit as such

Comment: how big is your list? how do you access it a lot? you can use a class/struct with the 2 int/float/double in a vector. a map will be faster to look for.a hash map even faster however if you don't have many points to iterate just use vector. so please tell us a little more details

Comment: BAsically what I am trying to do is calculate the distance between 2 points and store the points and distance in a data structure. Later find if the points are already present in that data structure if so then return the distance or else calculate the distance between the points and insert into the data structure

Comment: The main reason i am asking for a effective Data structure is because i have large set of points.

Comment: You may find this useful: http://stackoverflow.com/a/471461/78845

Comment: @Angel add the details in the comments into the question. A more detailed question renders more exact answers. I'll delete mine, it was not relevant.

Comment: I realise the title has been edited once already. But I find the current title overly general, to the point of near-uselessness. How about: _C++ Optimal data structure for memoization of simple function_? That's what you are looking for, no?

Comment: possible duplicate of [In which scenario do I use a particular STL Container?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/471432/in-which-scenario-do-i-use-a-particular-stl-container)

Answer (score 2):

You probably want to use `std::set` for the storage. You'll want/need a comparison function that takes the coordinates into account (the distance is directly derived from them, so you don't really need to compare it).

Edit: based on the comment that a large number of points is involved, an `std::unordered_set` may be a better choice. It'll probably be more work, but allows both insertion and searching with complexity you normally expect to be constant.

Answer (score 2):

Make that `std::unordered_set` with an appropriate hash.

Answer (score 1):

**EDIT:** The question changed, latitude/longitude are gone and some things have been clarified. I'm starting over:

Your question seems to imply that the distance calculation is not just a simple std::abs(X-Y), as it would make no sense at all to store the result to speed things up. I'll assume that you have an expensive function that calculates it, let's say:

```
int distance( int X, int Y ) { /* heavy stuff */ }
```

Now you need to decide whether or not to call it or if you have already done that and you can reuse the result. You need a container to store the results and a function to use it:

```
typedef std::pair< int, int > key;
std::map< key, int > values;

int quick_distance( int X, int Y )
{
  const auto k = key(X,Y);
  const auto it = values.find(k);
  if( it != values.end() ) return it->second;
  const auto d = distance(X,Y);
  values[k] = d;
  return d;
}
```

Comment: Basically what I am trying to do is calculate the distance between 2 points and store the points and distance in a data structure. Later find if the points are already present in that data structure if so then return the distance or else calculate the distance between the points and insert into the data structure.

Comment: Yes This is exactly what i was trying to do. I have a complex function which does distance calculation and I want to reuse the distance value instead of redoing it every time. Thank you :) It helped a lot

Comment: values[k] = d;   is nothing but values.insert(k, d); right ?

Comment: No, that would be `values.insert(std::make_pair(k,d))`.

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at std::pair, they was created for this purpose, and you could use improvements in containers associated with this kind of data structures.

[what-is-stdpair](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/97948/what-is-stdpair)

Time ago I wrote something using data pairs to graphics serial data from microcontrolers, check at https://github.com/jpcordovae/GLRealTimeGraphics/blob/master/DataPair.hpp, maybe it will help you.

Regards !

JP Cordova E.